# Java Multithread access data in shared Map

Tags: java, multithreading

I have a ConcurrentHashMap

```
public static Map<Short, Long> timer = new ConcurrentHashMap<Short, Long>();
```

Elements in this shared memory might be added or removed by two threads. When I try to access one of the value in a thread, how can I get rid of java.lang.NullPointerException?

Comment: Please provide a [MCVE](http://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve) to illustrate your issue.

Comment: Either perform an operation which cannot return null, or check for a null value before using it, just like any other situation where you work with references.

Comment: BTW ConcurrentHashMap is not a List.

Answer (score 1):

Quoting from [ConcurrentHashMap.get()](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/util/concurrent/ConcurrentHashMap.html#get-java.lang.Object-):

> Returns the value to which the specified key is mapped, or null if this map contains no mapping for the key.
>
> More formally, if this map contains a mapping from a key k to a value v such that key.equals(k), then this method returns v; otherwise it returns null. (There can be at most one such mapping.)
>
> Throws:
>       NullPointerException - if the specified key is null

As you can see, it only throws a `NullPointerException` if the given key is null. However, it also returns null if nothing is associated with the given key.

Here is an example that will work multi-threaded:

```
    ConcurrentHashMap<String, String> map = new ConcurrentHashMap<>();
    String key = "mykey";
    String value = map.get(key);
    if (value != null) {
        // use value
    } else {
        // no mapping for the given key
    }
```

You don't need synchronization, since the `get()` operation is atomic. Also, this will not throw a `NullPointerException` as long as you make sure that the key is never null.

Answer (score 0):

I think NULL check is the only way you can get rid of nullpointer exception. Because by definition, concurrent hashmap will allow you to add or delete from multiple threads.

You can always write a code like

**Not recommended:**

```
Map map = new ConcurrentHashMap<>();
synchronized(map){
   if(map.containcKey(key)){
      ///blah blah blah
   }
}
```

This will help you avoid nullpointer, but it defies the purpose of using concurrent hashmap. So having the code fail-safe is the only option, in my opinion.

Answer (score 0):

you can try it that way:

```
    Map<String, Optional<String>> map = new ConcurrentHashMap<>();
    map.getOrDefault(key, Optional.empty()).map(value -> /* do actual stuff here*/);
```